# VBA: Userform initialize method not being hit when userform initializes - UserForm.UserForm_Activate solution is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button on my worksheet where on click I have a assigned macro which calls the userform.show. See below:

```
Sub newjoin()
UserForm.UserForm_Activate
NewJoinerEntry.Show
End Sub
```

I've added the UserForm.UserForm_Activate looking at you above post.

Firstly I'm getting an error on UserForm.UserForm_Activate Run-time error '424' : Object required.

Additionally In my user form I have:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cntr As Integer
cntr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("SITES").Range("B2:B65536"))

Combosite.Clear
For obt = 2 To cntr
Me.Combosite.AddItem Cells(obt, 5)
Next obt
End Sub
```

**which I'm using to populate the combobox values & it's not happening**.

On the user form I have other code of on command button click to submit the form results and it's all fine there only if the combo box get the data when userform initializes.

Comment: You don't need to put this line: `UserForm.UserForm_Activate`. The `NewJoinerEntry.Show` should work fine, if it is the right name of the UserForm.

Comment: I have a problem loading the userform initialize. Actually i wanted to load the combo box with data once the form is initialized. NewJoinerEntry.Show is all fine

Comment: Are you creating a sub called `UserForm_Initialize()` in a module? If yes, of course it will not work. You need to open the UserForm, right click in a blank area, select the option Show Code and then, select the event  Initialize of that UserForm. You should put the code right there.

Comment: No. I've UserForm_Initialize() in my userform and in my modules i'm calling the userform - NewJoinerEntry.Show as it runs on a button which is on a worksheet.

Comment: In userform_Initialize i wanted to generate my combo box values from a range of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop in your range and add the values in a ComboBox like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SelectedRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SITES")
    LastRow = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SelectedRange = sh.Range("G2:G" & LastRow)

    ComboBox1.Clear

    For Each rng In SelectedRange
        ComboBox1.AddItem rng.Value
    Next rng

End Sub
```

This code will set a dynamic range in your sheet based on column B. As I saw in your original code, you want the values from column G. So, the `SelectedRange` is getting the the values from column G and putting it in a ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rafael. I get an Run time error '9' Subscript out of range  on LastRow = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: You need to verify your column B. I didn't see any erros on this code, I've tested it before.